# size of character array and size of character pointer

Tags: c, char, sizeof

I have a piece of C code and I don't understand how the `sizeof(...)` function works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
   const char  firstname[] = "bobby";
   const char* lastname = "eraserhead";
   printf("%lu\n", sizeof(firstname) + sizeof(lastname));
   return 0;
}
```

In the above code sizeof(firstname) is 6 and sizeof(lastname) is 8.

But `bobby` is 5 characters wide and `eraserhead` is 11 wide.  I expect `16`.

Why is sizeof behaving differently for the character array and pointer to character?

Can any one clarify?

Comment: Both `sizeof` and `strlen()` give a result of type `size_t`. Use `%zu`, not `%lu` to print `size_t` values. Or, if your compiler doesn't support `%zu`, convert to a known type and use the appropriate format for that type.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`firstname` is a `char` array carrying a trailing `0`-terminator. `lastname` is a pointer. On a 64bit system pointers are 8 byte wide.

Comment: Well it is clear that OP was trying to find out the size of the string  i.e. string length and add both of them as he says `" why not 5+10=15?"`,Is it really possible to get string length via `sizeof` or `strlen()` is more suitable? what do you say?

Comment: @PHIfounder: As **a "string" in C is represented by a sequence of characters terminated by a `'\0'` character**, use `strlen()` to get a "string"'s length. This works on "real" character arrays, as also on pointers pointing to the latter. In this context it is of no primary importance how and where the characters are stored. In fact the variable holding the string does not necessarily need to match the "string"'s length. If on the other hand one it interested in **the amount of bytes a variable is declared to use**, use the `sizeof` operator.

Comment: And the number of bytes needed to store a string `s` (or pointed to by `s`) is `strlen(s) + 1`.

Answer (score 6):

`sizeof` an array is the size of the total array, in the case of "bobby", it's 5 characters and one trailing `\0` which equals 6.

`sizeof` a pointer is the size of the pointer, which is normally 4 bytes in 32-bit machine and 8 bytes in 64-bit machine.

Answer (score 4):

The size of your first array is the size of `bobby\0`. `\0` is the terminator character, so it is 6.

The second size is the size of a pointer, which is 8 byte in your 64bit system. Its size doesn't depends on the assigned string's length.

Answer (score 4):

> how the sizeof(...) function works

`sizeof()` looks like a function but it's not a function. A function computes something at run-time.

`sizeof()` asks the compiler, *at compile-time*, how much *memory* it allocates for the argument. BTW `sizeof()` has no idea how much of it you actually use later at run time. In other words, you've "hardcoded" the `printf` arguments in your example.

> Why is sizeof behaving differently for the character array and pointer
>   to character?

A pointer rarely requires the same amount of memory as an array.

In general, the amount of memory allocated for a pointer is different to what is allocated for its pointee.

Answer (score 3):

`firstname` is an array of 6 `chars`, including the terminating `'\0'` character at the end of the string.  That's why `sizeof firstname` is 6.

`lastname` is a pointer to `char`, and will have whatever size such a pointer has on your system.  Typical values are 4 and 8.  The size of `lastname` will be the same no matter what it is pointing to (or even if it is pointing to nothing at all).

Answer (score 2):

`firstname[]` is null-terminated, which adds 1 to the length.

`sizeof(lastname)` is giving the size of the *pointer* instead of the actual value.

Comment: `*lastname` is a single `char`, so `sizeof *lastname` will always be 1.