# How to copy data from char [] to const char * whilst ignoring null

Tags: c++, udp

So i have a problem trying to send some data via a UDP socket. 
I need to use the sendto function to send a data packet. However, the function requires the data to be in the form of a const char *buf; the problem i run into is that my data is in the for a Char [] of size 1206 and when i try to convert the data, the conversion stop when it encounter a null. AND MY DATA HAS LOTS OF NULLS!!

So my question is, is there a way to convert char [] to a const char *buf whilst stopping it from null terminating?

I have Attached my current code and the data being printed:-

//CODE:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 1248
#define DTTMFMT "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S" 
#define DTTMSZ 21

using namespace std;
int SockConnRes, SendByte;  
int DataLen = 1248;
char buffer[1206];
string packet;

int main()
{
// LOTS OF UDP SOCKET CODE WAS HERE//

    do {
        SockConnRes = recvfrom(serverL, buffer, sizeof(buffer), NULL, (SOCKADDR *) &addr, &addrlen);    
        printf("byte: %d\n", SockConnRes);
        if (SockConnRes > 0)
        {
            MyFile << getDtTm (buff) << endl;
            printf("Data: %s\n", buffer);
            MyFile << "String: ";


 //For loop to print buffer data and to try and convert data into a
 //string but string packet just turned into another array//
            for (int printer = 0; printer < sizeof(buffer); printer++)
                {

                    printf("%x ", (unsigned char)buffer[printer]);
                    MyFile << "" << (unsigned char)buffer[printer];
                    packet += (unsigned char)buffer[printer];
                }
            printf("\n");
            MyFile << endl;
            const char *data = packet.c_str();
            DataLen = sizeof(data);
            printf("Data byte: %d\n", DataLen);
            cout << "String:" <<  data << endl; //PRINTING WHAT SHOULD BE STORED IN CONST CHAR *BUF
            SendByte = sendto(IPemotion, data, DataLen, 0, (SOCKADDR *) &IPeService, (int)sizeof(IPeService));
            printf("Sent byte: %d\n", SendByte);
            memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
            packet.clear();
            Sleep(500);
        }
        else if (SockConnRes == 0)
        {
            printf("Connection Closed\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("recv failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        }

       } while(SockConnRes > 0);

    MyFile.close();
    closesocket(serverL);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Result:
[IMAGE SHOWS STRING PRINTED BY BLUE PEN AND RED SHOWS WHERE 0 IS STOPPING THE CONVERSION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoMJc.png)
Any help is much appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: Please don't write in capital case.

Comment: How can you "copy" data to a `const char*`, given it's a `const`...?

Comment: [Possible dupe: "size of character array and size of character pointer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17260242/size-of-character-array-and-size-of-character-pointer).

Comment: `DataLen = sizeof(data);` doesn't do what you think it does... but I'm sure you know this because you used your debugger to work out what was going wrong right?

Comment: sorry for the caps lock......

not sure if i can copy, was just trying to copy/move the data to a const char........

the 'DataLen = sizeof(data);', didnt give any errors.. i thought this just measures the size of the 'data' at that instance.....

Comment: @AlvinKuruvilla 1) "_'DataLen = sizeof(data);', didnt give any errors_" Not all code that compiles works correctly. `sizeof` is compile-time construct. 2) Copy-paste the output in your console, not screenshot it.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius how do you copy and paste the output from the console? 
also the code is running on another computer.. thats why i just screen shot

Comment: @AlvinKuruvilla By copy-pasting it? How, exactly, depends on the platform/console. You can, just as easily, look it up.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you have data cut off is not because of nulls, it is because of this:

```
const char *data = packet.c_str();
DataLen = sizeof(data);
```

The `DataLen` is 4 because size of pointer is 4 bytes in your case so you only send 4 bytes.

Seeing that `packet` is a `string`, what you could try is pass the size of the packet like this:

```
DataLen = packet.size();
```

Comment: So how would i make the pointer (data) bigger? or even to the size of the buffer with all the actual data i have?

Comment: @AlvinKuruvilla you can't "make pointers bigger"... They are fixed length because your cpu uses that amount of bytes to address memory pages.

Comment: @killzone kid I tried this, and this just measures the packet size, which is 1206. And when i print whats in the 'data' variable, this still only prints out the first 4 byte until the two 00 i have in the buffer

Comment: @AlvinKuruvilla When you print, it will naturally assume this is a string and print until first `'\0'`. Print each byte from the loop: `for (int i = 0; i < DATASIZE; ++i) std::cout << DATA[i] << " ";`

Comment: @rpg711 how would i convert/copy or even move the data from either the buffer (which is a char []) or packet (which is a string array i think) to the const char *data?

Comment: @KillzoneKid i can print the data to the command prompt without any problem, what i need to do is.. send this data packet through the udp protocol, which uses the sendto function.. which needs the data buffer to be const char

Comment: You will not be able to get code to compile that reassigns or modifies a const. A const enforces constness, which by definition disallows modification in any way. You can memcpy the data to a non const char* but why would you want to do that? If you want to echo the char array that you receive, just send buffer back...?

Comment: @AlvinKuruvilla As @rpg711 mentioned, just sent buffer back. You dont need buffer to be const in order to pass it as argument to sendto `char buffer[3] = { 'a','b','c' }; const char *data = buffer;` works just fine

Comment: @rpg711 so your saying i cant do what i want.. as in change the variable the data is stored to a const char* ...?
there is no point for me to send the buffer back, because the software i am trying to send this lidar data only reads ascii.. so the whole code was meant to read the raw lidar data (hex) and convert it to a string or some form of ascii and send it out via udp protocols.. 
but thanks you for your help

Comment: @AlvinKuruvilla Okay. You're reading into the buffer, and then you want to send that out a UDP socket. Why do you want to copy that data into a const pointer? (you CANNOT copy anything into a const pointer, you can only copy data out of a const pointer, that's the entire point of declaring it const in the first place) Just send the read buffer out the socket.

Comment: @KillzoneKid when i tried to do that.. as in set **const char *data = buffer;** and ran the code.. some errors occured.. like the option to break the code kept coming up.. if that makes sense.. ill try get that error back again

Comment: @rpg711 i shall try send the buffer out through the sendto function

Comment: @AlvinKuruvilla This was not meant to be used literally, I was just showing you as an example that you can pass the `buffer` directly to `sendto` when it expects `const char *`. Take the `sizeof(buffer)` for the data length if you do.

Comment: @KillzoneKid oh okay, ahaha 

again thank you for all your help!!